# twitter bootstrap 3 jquery minimum version

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the **Minimum** version of `jquery` and `jquery-ui` to use with `Twitter bootstrap 3`? I have not found any documentation about that.

Comment: There is no need of jQuery UI for twitter bootstrap 3. The latest stable version of jquery is better.

Comment: The latest version may not work with the other libraries. I need to know the minimum version.

Comment: The latest jquery link code.jquery.com/jquery.js . Both are same.

Comment: If you are using more libraries, then 1.8 is perfect.

Answer (score 44):

I've just found this page on Bootstrap 3 "Getting Started" section.

For Bootstrap 3 there are dependencies on JQuery set to version 1.9.0 or higher

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

There you can find a link to their Bower file hosted on GitHub where is clearly written the minimum version of JQuery required by Bootstarp 3.0.2

Comment: Since version 3.3, Bootstrap throws a console error if an older jQuery version than 1.9.1 is used.

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.2/bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.9.0"
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json --> `"jquery": "1.9.1 - 3"`

Answer (score 7):

I'm putting this here because the last answer is from 2014:

I have bootstrap version 3.3.6, and if I update to JQuery 3.3.1 this error message appears in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

So lower than version 3, but higher than version 1.9.1 is fine, I just checked that and installed the latest 2.x version of JQuery, which can be found here:
https://code.jquery.com/

The one offered there is:
jQuery Core 2.2.4

Which just works fine with bootstrap version 3.3.6, and should be ok with version 3.3.7 officialy out.

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 3.1.1 requires Jquery 1.9.1 according to

Plugin dependencies
Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files). Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.
link to bower.json
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.1/bower.json

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone has actually tested Bootstrap 3 with different versions of jQuery.

I was using jQuery 1.3 when I tried to add a Bootstrap carousel.  It didn't work.  So I upgraded to 1.10 and it worked.  (I didn't go to 2.x because it doesn't support IE8 which I need.)

Unfortunately I now have to update other JS code because it's using .live which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

On their official website they uses version 1.10.2.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: any link to that page?

Comment: The fact that they use this version does not imply that it's the minimal version required.