# Bootstrap 3.2: menu button appears on resize but doesn't show the links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using the Default NavBar of Bootstrap 3.2. The collapse is working when the window is resized down, but the button is not displaying the links when cliked. This is what I have until now:

```
<body>
<div class="mainHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Test</a>
            </div>

             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">enlace1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">enlace2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">enlace3</a></li>                    
               </ul>           
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to verify your tags you have an additional DIV, i've tried it on [bootply.com](http://bootply.com) its working fine

```
    <body>
      <div class="mainHeader">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Test</a>
      </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">enlace1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">enlace2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">enlace3</a></li>                    
           </ul>           
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
     </nav>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**

you have to consider adding `<div class="container">` under the **nav** tag, like the updated code !

**UPDATE 2**

you have to check the jQuery minimum version required by bootstrap3 [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891829/twitter-bootstrap-3-jquery-minimum-version)

Comment: Well, there was a missing DIV :P, but fixed that the button still doesn't works.

Comment: I just have signed up. I still can't login.

Comment: @sergio i've updated my answer & code !, and you don't have to login to **bootply** to test your code

Comment: I did test it in bootply and runs as a charm, but still won't run locally. I'll restart...

Comment: The exact same code runs in bootply but not here. I did test several browsers. I did test a version placed in the desktop and another places in the localhost.

Comment: try uploading the source code (Ctrl + U), and let me see it (on gist or jsfiddle),

Comment: Please, review it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiourra/1tpf3ohg/) . Many Thanks.

Comment: I have tryed changing the link to jquery.min.js (version 1.4.1) to [jquery-latest.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js") (version 1.11.1) and it worked. Please, write the solution in your answer in order to mark it as the correct one. Many thanks for your help and have a nice day.