# Version of jQuery for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Problem statement:
I cannot find info at getbootstrap about what version of jQuery use Bootstrap 3?

Do you know?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891829/twitter-bootstrap-3-jquery-minimum-version)?

Comment: There is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891829/twitter-bootstrap-3-jquery-minimum-version). which has [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) in which there is `>= 1.9.1` in file. Googled in 30 seconds.

Comment: That is about 'twitter bootstrap 3'

Answer (score 3):

It is given in their bower.json: jquery": ">= 1.9.1"

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "description": "The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.",
  "version": "3.3.4",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "js",
    "less",
    "mobile-first",
    "responsive",
    "front-end",
    "framework",
    "web"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://getbootstrap.com",
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "/.*",
    "_config.yml",
    "CNAME",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "docs",
    "js/tests",
    "test-infra"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
   "jquery": ">= 1.9.1" //SEE This
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what version of bootstrap use jquery-1.10.2.min?

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: Bootsrap 3.3.4 will be able to use jquery-1.10.2 because it erquires Jquery greater tha 1.9.1 and bootstrap 3.3.4 is the latest bootstrap release.