# bootstrap min css link is effecting my module popups

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I have been developing basic website for a final year project, i added module popup but as soon as i started to add Bootstrap min.css files for my navigation bar jQuery is not working even though i have but it first the jQuery links before any other bootstrap links. if i removed the bootstrap.min.css link is working fine but i need for my navigation bar.

below is how i linked. am using version 3.3.7

```
<script src="Scripts22/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts22/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Below i have attached how it is function when all the links are there.

Comment: I need help please. how to have both links to work together without conflicting each other.

Comment: checkout this so for ordering [ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926086/script-order-for-jquery-with-bootstrap)

Comment: I order them so many times.nothing is working till i remove one of them.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using and what version of jquery does it require?

Comment: Have you tried updating to a newer version of jquery? 1.8.2 is very old

Comment: am using version 3. i will try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap 3 jquery minimum version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891829/twitter-bootstrap-3-jquery-minimum-version)

Comment: looks like the minimum is 1.9.1 for v3

Comment: even the newer version of jquery which is 3 is not working.